# Mathematical series regarding complex (I think)

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers

$\sum _{k=1}^{n-1} (n-k)\cos\frac{2k\pi}{n} $

I smell complex here...something regarding $n^{th}$ roots of unity... But I think there might be a catch...after all:
$n\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\cos\frac{2k\pi}{n} -[ \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} cos\frac{2k\pi}{n}] -[\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} cos\frac{2k\pi}{n}]-[\sum_{k=3}^{n-1} cos\frac{2k\pi}{n}].........-[\sum_{k=(n-2)}^{n-1} cos\frac{2k\pi}{n}]-cos\frac{2\pi}{n}$

I think the sums can be calculated with the appropriate limits by he formula which involve angles in AP. But is there a bett way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using  [Euler's Formula](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler%27s_Formula),

$\displaystyle\sum _{k=1}^{n-1} (n-k)\cos\frac{2k\pi}{n}= $
Real of $\displaystyle\sum _{k=1}^{n-1} (n-k)e^{\frac{2k\pi i}n}=$
Real of $\displaystyle\sum _{k=1}^{n-1} (n-k)(e^{\frac{2\pi i}n})^k$

Now,  $\displaystyle\sum _{k=1}^{n-1} (n-k) x^k=n\sum _{k=1}^{n-1}x^k-\sum _{k=1}^{n-1} k x^k$

Again, $\displaystyle\sum _{k=1}^{n-1} k x^k=x\frac{d(\sum _{k=0}^{n-1}x^k)}{dx}$